# How to extract loss and accuracy from logger by each epoch in pytorch lightning?

Tags: logging, pytorch, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I want to extract all data to make the plot, not with tensorboard. My understanding is all log with loss and accuracy is stored in a defined directory since tensorboard draw the line graph.

```
%reload_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir lightning_logs/
```

[image]

However, I wonder how all log can be extracted from the logger in pytorch lightning. The next is the code example in training part.

```
#model
ssl_classifier = SSLImageClassifier(lr=lr)

#train
logger = pl.loggers.TensorBoardLogger(name=f'ssl-{lr}-{num_epoch}', save_dir='lightning_logs')

trainer = pl.Trainer(progress_bar_refresh_rate=20,
                            gpus=1,
                            max_epochs = max_epoch,
                            logger = logger,
                            )

trainer.fit(ssl_classifier, train_loader, val_loader)
```

I had confirmed that `trainer.logger.log_dir` returned directory which seems to save logs and `trainer.logger.log_metrics` returned `<bound method TensorBoardLogger.log_metrics of <pytorch_lightning.loggers.tensorboard.TensorBoardLogger object at 0x7efcb89a3e50>>`.

`trainer.logged_metrics` returned only the log in the final epoch, like

```
{'epoch': 19,
 'train_acc': tensor(1.),
 'train_loss': tensor(0.1038),
 'val_acc': 0.6499999761581421,
 'val_loss': 1.2171183824539185}
```

Do you know how to solve the situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightning do not store all logs by itself. All it does is *streams* them into the `logger` instance and the logger decides what to do.

The best way to retrieve all logged metrics is by having a custom callback:

```
class MetricTracker(Callback):

  def __init__(self):
    self.collection = []

  def on_validation_batch_end(trainer, module, outputs, ...):
    vacc = outputs['val_acc'] # you can access them here
    self.collection.append(vacc) # track them

  def on_validation_epoch_end(trainer, module):
    elogs = trainer.logged_metrics # access it here
    self.collection.append(elogs)
    # do whatever is needed
```

You can then access all logged stuff from the callback instance

```
cb = MetricTracker()
Trainer(callbacks=[cb])

cb.collection # do you plotting and stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is not fundamentally wrong but does not follow the official (current) guidelines by Pytorch-Lightning.

As suggested here: https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/logging.html#make-a-custom-logger

It is suggested to write a class like:

```
from pytorch_lightning.utilities import rank_zero_only
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import LightningLoggerBase
from pytorch_lightning.loggers.base import rank_zero_experiment


class MyLogger(LightningLoggerBase):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return "MyLogger"

    @property
    @rank_zero_experiment
    def experiment(self):
        # Return the experiment object associated with this logger.
        pass

    @property
    def version(self):
        # Return the experiment version, int or str.
        return "0.1"

    @rank_zero_only
    def log_hyperparams(self, params):
        # params is an argparse.Namespace
        # your code to record hyperparameters goes here
        pass

    @rank_zero_only
    def log_metrics(self, metrics, step):
        # metrics is a dictionary of metric names and values
        # your code to record metrics goes here
        pass

    @rank_zero_only
    def save(self):
        # Optional. Any code necessary to save logger data goes here
        # If you implement this, remember to call `super().save()`
        # at the start of the method (important for aggregation of metrics)
        super().save()

    @rank_zero_only
    def finalize(self, status):
        # Optional. Any code that needs to be run after training
        # finishes goes here
        pass
```

By looking inside the class `LightningLoggerBase`, one can see some suggestions of function that could be overriden.

Here is a minimalistic loggers of mine. It is highly not optimised, but would be a good first shot. I will edit if I improved it.

```
import collections

from pytorch_lightning.loggers import LightningLoggerBase
from pytorch_lightning.loggers.base import rank_zero_experiment
from pytorch_lightning.utilities import rank_zero_only

class History_dict(LightningLoggerBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.history = collections.defaultdict(list) # copy not necessary here  
        # The defaultdict in contrast will simply create any items that you try to access

    @property
    def name(self):
        return "Logger_custom_plot"

    @property
    def version(self):
        return "1.0"

    @property
    @rank_zero_experiment
    def experiment(self):
        # Return the experiment object associated with this logger.
        pass

@rank_zero_only
def log_metrics(self, metrics, step):
    # metrics is a dictionary of metric names and values
    # your code to record metrics goes here
    for metric_name, metric_value in metrics.items():
        if metric_name != 'epoch':
            self.history[metric_name].append(metric_value)
        else: # case epoch. We want to avoid adding multiple times the same. It happens for multiple losses.
            if (not len(self.history['epoch']) or    # len == 0:
                not self.history['epoch'][-1] == metric_value) : # the last values of epochs is not the one we are currently trying to add.
                self.history['epoch'].append(metric_value)
            else:
                pass
    return

    def log_hyperparams(self, params):
        pass
```